# Error in applying Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities

I'm trying to solve a problem using Chebychev^' s Inequality:

"Suppose that X is a random variable with mean and variance both equal to 20. What can be said about P(0<X<40)?"

P(|X-μ|≥kσ)≤1/k^2

> Restating the original equation:
>
> P(0<X<40)=P(|X-20|≤20)
>
> Rewriting to match Chebychev's Inequality
>
> P(|X-20|≤20)≤1-  1/k^2 ;k>0
>
> Find k:
> P(|X-20|≤(kσ=20))≤1-1/k^2
>
> P(|X-20|≤(k√20=20))≤1-  1/k^2
>
> P(|X-20|≤(k=√20))≤1-  1/k^2
>
> P(|X-20|≤20)≤1-1/20
>
> P(|X-20|≤20)≤19/20
>
> The probability that X falls between 0 and 40 is less than or equal to 0.95.

Now, I know that my answer is wrong. I am either sloppy at inequalities, or I don't understand how to use them correctly.

In this case, the correct answer should be

> P(|X-20|≤20)≥19/20.

Can anyone help me understand where my misunderstanding is?

Here's an image that may be easier to read:
[image: screen capture of work.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is false:
$P(|X-20|≤20)≤1- 1/k^2 ;k>0$.

You started with:
$A=P(|X-20|\geq20)≤ 1/k^2=B$.

To get to the next line, you need to change the direction of the inequality because you multiply both side by a negative constant ($-1$):

$$A\leq B \Rightarrow 1-A \geq 1-B$$

Comment: I see it now. Ugh.